# Asp.net c# Modify web config section value on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, runtime

I am trying to figure out 2 things (1) identify a section in the web config (2) change value on button click

```
<location path="General" allowOverride="true">
<system.web>

  <authorization>   
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
   </location>
```

I am trying out figure out on btn click how to change:

```
<deny users="*" />
to 
 <deny users="?" />
```

also, if this is possible will now

```
<deny users="?" />
```

becomes default unless it is changed again?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bad idea. Not only are you giving a user of your site write control of the site's Web.config file (a security risk), the instant it changes, the AppDomain will recycle and terminate the request (because the Web.config file changed).

Comment: Thanks. on btn click we are checking if a user is logged in and if logged in we are allowing the user access to the General folder. Idea is to disallow all user including search engines to access General folder unless they have been authenticated. We are not using asp.net membership framework as it seems to be now too late in life.

Comment: You're still missing the point that changing the sites own configuration file from the site itself will terminate the HTTP request in the browser requesting the change. Security aside, that's a bad UX.

Comment: And that change will affect ALL users of the site, not just the one clicking the button.

Comment: Got you..much appreciated. Any idea how do we conditionally allow access to a folder with confidential documents with out using membership framework. Like I mentioned it seems too late for us now to change our login module to Membership framework. Kind of become very tired trying to figure this out now for a week or so.

Comment: Using roles is the only way to do it really.

Comment: Thanks. I value your time and advise. Lot of my other friends suggested on the same line. Seems like I have been hoping against hope. I think I need a drink.